# Android Room Unsure what to do with methods return type

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-guava

I'm following Android Developers documentation and from this I have the following in my DAO:

```
@Insert(onConflictStrategy = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
ListenableFuture<Integer> insertProjects(Project... projects);
```

When I was using type `void` I'm able to intialise the database properly and use the method as expected. However, when I use ListenableFuture, and run it, build comes out with the following error:

```
Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.

ListenableFuture<Integer> insertProjects(Project... projects);
                          ^
```

The docs don't actually tell me how to use this let alone say that an error would ensue upon it's usage.

EDIT:

The docs say this:

```
// Returns the number of users inserted.
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public ListenableFuture<Integer> insertUsers(List<User> users);
```

What is happening and how can I fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert):

> If the @Insert method receives a single parameter, it can return a long value, which is the new rowId for the inserted item. If the parameter is an array or a collection, then the method should return an array or a collection of long values instead

So try this instead:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
ListenableFuture<List<Long>> insertProjects(Project... projects);
```

Comment: I've added an edit to what the docs say as to what that Integer is holding... Is this not right then?

Comment: I think docs are clear enough. 1. `Long` - not `Integer`. 2. If you insert array or collection, then method should return array or collection as well, not just one value